# Can't use property outside of XMLHttpRequest callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to get some data from a XMLHttpRequest `onreadystatechange` callback. I can successfully log the data and everything works fine, until I try to use this data outside from the callback function: `this.processedData.next(xttp)`. This returns the following error:

```
core.js:5828 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'processedData' of undefined
    at callbackXttp (output.service.ts:55)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (output.service.ts:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone-evergreen.js:1202)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:40744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:481)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1596)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1622)
```

That's probably because this request is async, but I thought I'd solve this by using a callback function.

```
export class OutputService {

  processedData: ReplaySubject<any>;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.processedData = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  }

  doCalculation(a, b, z) {
    this.request(a, b, z, this.callbackXttp);
  }

  request(a, b, z, callback) {
    const V = {classes: a, absolute: b, z};
    const Val = JSON.stringify(V);
    let response = 0;
    console.log('Request Data: ' + Val);
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback(response);
      }
    };

    xhttp.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send(Val);
  }

  callbackXttp(xttp) {
    const object = [
      ...
    ];
    this.processedData.next(xttp);
    this.router.navigate(['/output']);
  }

  getProcessedData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.processedData.asObservable();
  }
}
```

My test call inside of another component:

```
this.outputService.doCalculation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 5, 8, 3], 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `this.callbackXttp` as an argument to `this.request`:

```
  doCalculation(a, b, z) {
    this.request(a, b, z, this.callbackXttp);
  }
```

Then you are calling it here:

```
callback(response);
```

Since you are just calling it as a function, not `something.callback()`, the `this` value inside `callbackXttp` will be `undefined`, and that is why you are getting that error here:

```
this.processedData.next(xttp);
```

Possible solution, `.bind` the function before passing it around:

```
    this.request(a, b, z, this.callbackXttp.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change:

```
this.request(a, b, z, this.callbackXttp);
```

to

```
this.request(a, b, z, xttp => this.callbackXttp(xttp));
```

Also, I assume you have a good reason for not using the Angular HttpClient?

Edit:

Ultimately, I think you're running into trouble because you're using a non-arrow function here

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
}
```

Which means that the `this.` calls in `callbackXttp` are no longer referring to the class, but to the function.

Instead of my previous suggestion, try changing

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
}
```

to

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
}
```

(And then try changing to HttpClient...)